# why axios response becomes slower as the rate of request becomes faster and longer the request keeps calling

Tags: node.js, axios, artillery, axios-retry

I am using artillery to send different rate of request to an `nodejs` API that makes an `axios` post request, and the response time seems to be increasing as time goes by.

e.g. when sending 10 req/sec to the API, the response time are around 100-300ms for the `axios` post request, however after maybe an hour, as the request continues to call the API, the response time for the `axios` slowly climbs to several seconds.

another e.g. when sending at 30 req/sec, the response time also starts around 100-300ms, then immediately, the response time climbs to 1-3 seconds, and after a few more seconds, response time becomes 1min+.

My API have this `axios` request:

```
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true })

const axiosRetry = require('axios-retry')
const axios = require('axios')

const method = async (URL, request, headers) => {
    const now = Date.now()
    console.time('axios call ' + now)
    axiosRetry(axios, {
        retries: 3,
        retryDelay: () => {
            return 5000
        },
        retryCondition: (error) => {
            return error.response.status === 503;
        }
    })

    await axios.post(URL, request, {
        headers,
        timeout: 60000,
        httpsAgent
    })
    console.timeEnd('axios call ' + now)

}
```

I have tried using artillery to call the `axios's` URL directly and the response time seems stable around 110ms, despite calling at 30 req/sec for about 1 hour duration.
hence I think I'm narrowing down to this `axios` request.

Comment: What service are you calling? Could it be that the server handling the requests is unable to keep up with the traffic?